# How to solve the delay in loading the radio button selection in the application?

Tags: java, gwt

In my application, i have a radio button field selected. When i am opening the page, the selected field has some delay. Example: I am opening the page, that radio button is in unselected state, after some time (say like hovering on the screen/scrolling) the radio button turns to selected state. Is there is any other way to solve this delay?

```
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
            @Override
            public void execute() {
                    statementGroupSelectionModel.setSelected(item, profile.getSelected());
            }
        });
```

Here in the above code, "item" is widget field name and depending upon my "getselected" value, the radio icon will get selected. Here my "getSelected" value is true.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but you can subscribe to changes instead of getting the current value so whenever the delay makes the value change, you will update your selection.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? i tried using the scheduled deffered methods, but i didnt get the proper output which i have expected to do behave so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any code inside `scheduleDeferred` will have its execution postponed until the browser finishes rendering the page and the flow control returns to the Javascript event loop, as explained in [GWT's documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDelayed.html):

> **Deferring some logic into the immediate future: the Scheduler class**
>   Sometimes you want to break up your logic loop so that the JavaScript event loop gets a chance to run between two pieces of code. The `Scheduler` class will allow you to do that. The logic that you pass to Scheduler will run at some point in the future, after control has been returned to the JavaScript event loop. This little delay may give the interface a chance to process some user events or initialize other code. To use the `Scheduler` class in its simplest form, you create a subclass of the `Command` class, overriding the `execute()` method and pass it to `Scheduler.scheduleDeferred`

If what you want is for the radio button to be selected immediately, just remove the `Scheduler` wrapping, i.e. move `statementGroupSelectionModel.setSelected(item, profile.getSelected());` out of `scheduleDeferred`.

```
// Put this here
statementGroupSelectionModel.setSelected(item, profile.getSelected());

// Remove the following code
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
        ...
        });
```

If what you want is not that (sorry, your explanation is rather unclear), but just to be able to set the delay time yourself instead of having to wait for the browser, you can use the `Timer` class which is explained in the documentation linked above.